# Can't connect existing postgres database on heroku via rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

So basically, it is working on my localhost, but when I do the following command line in terminal.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error message.

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "XX.XX.XX.XX" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port XXXX?
```

Here's the index method I have on one of my controller in my rails

```
def index
  sql = "Select * from api.customer"
  @examples = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  render json: @examples
end
```

database.yml file

`development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: 10`

`production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: 10`

I have included the database info(host, port, database name, username, password) in my database.yml file. Everything in terms of the database info is correct since I multi multi checked before asking. My host is in the format of ip address. I also checked the database with pgadmin 3 and the server configuration(pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf) is open to all ip addresses. (0.0.0.0/0 md5 and listens to '*') Please advise on what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set up a database on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, I have tried heroku-postgres add on, and it creates a random generated database for me. I also went inside the config and add a variable call DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pw@IP:port/dbName

Answer (score 0):

In Rails the `DATABASE_URL` ENV var has precedence over any value entered in `database.yml`.

Heroku sets the Rails database by the `DATABASE_URL` ENV var (Heroku uses the term config vars  which is the exact same thing). It does this automatically when the buildpack detects that you are deploying a rails app after it attaches the postgres addon.

To connect to another DB you need to change `DATABASE_URL`:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx/myapp
```

See:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: if you are still getting a timeout the URL is incorrect or your Postgres server is not properly set up. Use pg_isready to check. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pg-isready.html

Comment: Sorry for my lack of codes in the post, but I have the DATABASE_URL ENV in database.yml already. Please see below for it or post for it. I ran pg_isready and it returned accepting connections

Comment: ```development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: 10
```

Comment: Adding `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` to `database.yml` actually does nothing since rails merges `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` with the file based config anyways.

Comment: Is it possible that because the migration takes more than 30 seconds in which causes the 'dyno' to timeout, thus, causing this problem in heroku? Please let me know if this made sense

Comment: Yeah that definitely changes things. I though you where having a problem connecting to PG at all. If your migration takes more than 30 seconds you´re doing something very wrong or doing something that should not be done in a migration but rather something like a rake task that is more fault tolerant.

Comment: So how should/can I have my rails connect to a remote postgresql database? Sorry that I wasn't clear before. I have looked up most documentations and still haven't found a solution to this. I thought initially it was to change the database.yml, and it did work for me locally. Everything works locally. Only when it comes to db:migrate to heroku, it failed. Are there any code examples out there that I can take a look and review?

Comment: Quick note: it didn't take more than 10 sec to do db:migrate on localhost

Comment: is it possible that it's because the host ip address is private(not sure, but its within the private ip range) and can't be access out of network?